# How to set post parameters on using Alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire in swift to send http request/post to server. Below is the code I used in swift.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/hello", headers: [ACCESS_TOKEN:token, "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  ],
            parameters:["friend_id" : friendId, "skill_id" : skillId]).response(completionHandler: {
                (request, response, data, error) in
                print(request)
                print(response)
                print(data)
                print(error)
            })
```

Below is the code defined in server side:

```
@POST
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response nominateSkill(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @FormParam("friend_id") long friendId, @FormParam("skill_id") int skillId) {
    // ...
}
```

When I run the swift code, I always got below error message in server side:

```
A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8080/hello contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

I think the problem would be coursed by the swift code which didn't set the parameter correctly. But I don't know how to set them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after some search. I need to add "encoding: .URL" on the request method like below:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/hello", headers: [ACCESS_TOKEN:token, "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  ],
        parameters:["friend_id" : friendId, "skill_id" : skillId],
        encoding: .URL).response(completionHandler: {
            (request, response, data, error) in
            print(request)
            print(response)
            print(data)
            print(error)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your swift code seems fine. Make sure on which side problem is occur. You can try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en to test the api and make sure api doen't have any issues.

You may also try to change data type of friend_id and skill_id to string in server side and run again.